# Yield outliers of a mutual fund

Tags: outliers

I am trying to analyze real estate mutual funds and currently I am working on monthly yields (using 16th of each month).
I have 98 monthly yields with at least 2 outliers and want to use these yields for further analysis (Value at Risk mostly).

```
0.40
-4.26
-0.89
0.35
0.15
-0.74
0.33
0.26
-1.11
0.31
0.31
-1.05
0.33
0.31
-1.00
0.34
0.33
-0.49
0.21
0.13
-0.89
0.21
0.25
-0.32
0.14
0.16
-0.47
0.35
0.19
-0.34
0.14
0.17
-0.56
0.19
0.30
-0.57
0.24
0.35
-0.54
0.12
0.21
-0.55
0.39
0.21
-0.63
0.21
0.25
-0.68
0.30
0.33
-0.64
0.30
0.59
-0.58
0.28
0.24
-0.02
0.31
0.21
-0.07
0.25
0.22
0.39
0.27
0.17
0.16
0.18
0.52
0.32
0.38
0.20
0.17
0.19
2.35
0.21
0.02
0.41
0.45
0.41
-9.73
0.27
0.06
0.29
0.84
0.18
1.99
0.31
-0.14
0.12
0.29
-0.21
0.27
0.25
0.09
0.22
0.32
0.24
0.30
```

The outliers of -9,73% and -4,26% were caused by the real estate fund when it changed the value of assets to fit the fair price, or at least to make it as fair as possible.
These yields come since 16.8.2007 to 16.9.2015, the real estate fund 
was established on 2.4.2007.
I looked into some Extreme Value Theory and tried to find some distributions to fit these data, cause I doubt it would be wise to just ignore these outliers.
So I'd like to ask, is it wise to ignore these outliers and if not, would it be a good idea to use distribution like "Generalized Extreme Value distribution"?